# Multi level add more button using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to develop a multilevel add more button using jquery.

I did that functionality, but its not success. It has many bugs. Some Logical issues are there...

My actual requirement there is one "Add more" button. When we click this add more button one Div will open. In side that div there is one text box and another one "add more" button

For example,  First i add the main option value is "Bajaj". Under this option i want to add some options like "Discover", "Platina",...

Then i click next add more button and add the next option value is "Yamaha" under this Option i need to add sub options like FZ,YBR, Ray...

```
<div id="tabularoptions">
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add Options" />
<br />
<br />
<div id="TextBoxContainer">
    <!--Textboxes will be added here -->
    <?php
    if ($form['tabularOptions'] != '') {
        foreach ($form['tabularOptions'] as $opt) {
            ?>
            <div  style="border:1px solid #ccc;margin: 10px;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Option Value :</td>
                        <td>
                            <input name = 'tabluarOptionValue_<?php echo $opt['id']; ?>' type="text" value = "<?php echo $opt['tabularOptionValue']; ?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="tabluarOptionId_<?php echo $opt['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $opt['id']; ?>">
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove" /></td>


                        <?php
                        if ($form['tabularSubOptions'] != '') {
                            foreach ($form['tabularSubOptions'] as $optsub) {
                                if ($optsub['tabularOptionId'] == $opt['id']) {
                                    ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="tabularSuboptionValue_<?php echo $optsub['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $optsub['tabularSuboptionValue']; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="tabularSuboptionId_<?php echo $optsub['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $optsub['id']; ?>">
                                        <input type="button" class="subOptionRemove" value="X">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ?> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <table>
                        <tr class="subOptionDiv">
                            <td><input class = "btnAdd1" type="button" value = "Add Suboptions" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>


<?php
}
```

}
?>

```
</div>
```

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
        var div = $("<div />");
        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
    });
    $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
    });



    $("body").on("click",".btnAdd1", function () {

      $(this).closest("table").append('<tr>\n\
                                            <td>\n\
                                                <input type="text" name="tabularSuboptionValue_'+j+'[]">\n\
                                                <input type="button" class="subOptionRemove" value="X">\n\
                                            </td>\n\
                                        </tr>');

    });

    $("body").on("click",".subOptionRemove", function () {
       $(this).parent().remove();
    });




});
var j = 1;
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {

                                    j=j+1;

                                    $('#optionCount').val(j);


                                   // alert(j);
        return '<div id='+j+'  style="border:1px solid #ccc;margin: 10px;"><table>\n\
                    <tr>\n\
                        <td>Option Value :</td>\n\
                        <td><input name = "tabluarOptionValue_'+j+'[]" type="text" value = "' + value + '" /></td>\n\
                        <td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove" /></td>\n\
                    </tr>\n\
                    <tr>\n\
                    </tr>\n\
                       <tr>\n\
                            <table>\n\
                                <tr class="subOptionDiv"><td><input class = "btnAdd1" type="button" value = "Add Suboptions" /></td></tr>\n\
                                    <tr>\n\
                                    <td>\n\
                                        <input type="text" name="tabularSuboptionValue_'+j+'[]">\n\
                                        <input type="button" class="subOptionRemove" value="X">\n\
                                    </td>\n\
                                </tr>\n\
                            </table>\n\
                        </tr>\n\
                </table></div>';


}


</script>
```

Comment: you have some code for that right?

Comment: Post the code Make more sense

Comment: Dear friend, i developed in Kohana... I will post that code..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code may be usefull for you.

Put this jquery/javascript code where you js code is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

Put this code in your php/html file where you want the text box.

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="type">
    <tr >
        <td align="left">Subcategory</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Type : <input type="text" name="type" id="type" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" > 
        <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="subtype1"> 
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Subtype : <input type="text" name="type" id="type" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
            <div>
                <input type="button" name="addsub" value="Add Subtype" onclick="addmore('1')" />
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div>      
    <input type="button" name="add" value="Add Type" onclick="addmoretype()" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
num = 2;
function addmore(id)
{
    var tablename = "#subtype"+id;
    $(tablename+' tr:last').after('<tr><td> Subtype: <input type="text" name="type" id="type" />    </td>   </tr>');
}   

function addmoretype()
{
    $('#type tr:last').after('<tr>  <td>Type : <input type="text" name="type" id="type" /></td></tr>    <tr>    <td><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >   <tr>    <td>    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="subtype'+ num+'">   <tr>    <td>    Subtype : <input type="text" name="type" id="type" /></td></tr> </table></td>   </tr><tr>   <td>    <div>   <input type="button" name="addsub" value="Add Subtype" onclick="addmore('+ num+')" />   </div>  </td>   </tr></table>   </td></tr>');
    num++;
}
```

[see working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8bjxhg27/1/)

Comment: In my understanding, this is not the behaviour @Franklin was expecting.

Comment: This code is logicaly wrong. Because you are  using num++, when we go for edit option it will not work for multilevel.  Next thing is I need Multilevel add more

Comment: I am edited the answer. please check now. it may help you.

Comment: Dear  Shailesh, Thank you for your valuable support. Your code is working. I am expecting this only.  But how can i get this values for insertion. And also i need to update this. Actually Already i did these steps... you can check my code... Where i struggle means the edit and the update portion for this. because after posting we need to identify which sub option is comes under which option.... Also need to remove option..